# В ListView при поиске сбивается позиция

Tags: android, listview

Нужно реализовать правильный переход на новое активити, использую ListView,
SearchView, ListVIewAdapter. Если не использовать поиск, то position правильно
работает, но если найти какой-то элемент в поиске, например, его position=9, а
при поиске будет 0. Как исправить?

AnimalNames для ListView

```
public class AnimalNames {
    private String animalName;
    private String country;
    private Integer population;
    private Integer population_a;
    public AnimalNames(String country, String animalName, Integer population, Integer population_a) {
        this.animalName = animalName;
        this.country = country;
        this.population = population;
        this.population_a = population_a;

    }

    public String getAnimalName() {
        return this.animalName;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return this.country;
    }
    public Integer getPopulation() {
        return this.population;
    }
    public Integer getPopulation_a() {
        return this.population_a;
    }

}
```

для ListView

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<AnimalNames> animalNamesList = null;
    private ArrayList<AnimalNames> arraylist;
    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<AnimalNames> animalNamesList) {
        mContext = context;
        this.animalNamesList = animalNamesList;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<AnimalNames>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(animalNamesList);
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView tema;
        ImageView imgid;
        ImageView imgid1;
        Button button;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return animalNamesList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public AnimalNames getItem(int position) {
        return animalNamesList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, null,true);
            // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
            holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name_tema);
            holder.tema = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtStatusMsg);
            holder.imgid = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
            holder.imgid1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        // Set the results into TextViews
        holder.name.setText(animalNamesList.get(position).getAnimalName());
        holder.tema.setText(animalNamesList.get(position).getCountry());
        holder.imgid.setImageResource(animalNamesList.get(position).getPopulation());
        holder.imgid1.setImageResource(animalNamesList.get(position).getPopulation_a());
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.butt);
button.setClickable(false);
        button.setFocusable(false);
        return view;
    }

    // Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        animalNamesList.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            animalNamesList.addAll(arraylist);
        } else {
            for (AnimalNames wp : arraylist) {
                if (wp.getAnimalName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)
                        ||wp.getCountry().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)  ) {
                    animalNamesList.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}
```

MainActivity

```
 list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    for (int i = 0; i < animalNameList.length; i++) {
        AnimalNames animalNames = new AnimalNames(animalNameList[i],country[i],population[i],population_a[i]);
        // Binds all strings into an array
        arraylist.add(animalNames);
    }

    // Pass results to ListViewAdapter Class
    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, arraylist);

    // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, final long id) {

        }
    });

        // Locate the EditText in listview_main.xml
    editsearch = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    editsearch.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    String text = newText;
    adapter.filter(text);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Так происходит потому, что после поиска вы создаете новый список, у которого свои позиции. В модели заведите еще поле `position` и читайте позицию из него, а не позицию в списке.

Comment: @pavlofff ,а можно пример ,потому что я только начал изучать ,был бы очень благодарен вам

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В класс-модель добавляем поле `position` (устанавливается через первый аргумент конструктора):

```
public class AnimalNames {
    ...
    private long position;

    public AnimalNames(long position, String country, String animalName, Integer population, Integer population_a) {
    ...
    this.position = position;
    }

    ...
    public long getPosition() {
        return this.position;
    }

}
```

В адаптере делаем метод, возвращающий абсолютную позицию. Воспользуемся четвертым аргументом колбэка `onItemClick()` - `id`, так как он все равно не используется в списках, не связанных с БД и это избавит нас от лишнего кода:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    ...
    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<AnimalNames> animalNamesList) {
    ...
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return animalNamesList.get(position).getPosition();
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Теперь нам нужно заполнить в модель абсолютные позиции (указываем в первом аргументе в качестве позиции счетчик цикла):

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
for (int i = 0; i < animalNameList.length; i++) {
    AnimalNames animalNames = new AnimalNames(i, animalNameList[i],country[i],population[i],population_a[i]);
    arraylist.add(animalNames);
}

adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, arraylist);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        // здесь при клике на айтеме возвращается третий аргумент
        // текущая позиция в списке (position) - с учетом фильтра.
        // Четвертый аргумент (id) - абсолютная позиция, без учета фильтра

    }
});
```

Не изменённые части кода пропущены.

Comment: спасибо за подробное объяснение ,а можете мне написать для примера   ,что именно нужно писать в onItemClick,потому что у меня не выходит,за ранее спасибо.

Comment: @fcbarcafc Там где вам нужно значение позиции, которая была в полном списке пишите переменную `id`

Comment: да я все понял все получилось  огромное вам спасибо за помощь